# How to import ts and html with getStaticProps for a static site in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to render static data that is coming from a typescript file and display it to the user. As far as I know, I have to use getStaticProps to make the site static. But I'm getting an error because it's not a `JSON` file. Do I really have to put it through getStaticProps to make it static or as it is a javascript import like a component just with data it is static by default? How would I work around the Error message below?

**Error:**

```
Error: Error serializing `.projects[0].extra.$$typeof` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/index".
Reason: `symbol` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

**projects.tsx**

```
const projects: [
  {
    id: "6853939",
    name: "Project 01",
    title: "Title 01 ",
    previewImg: "/images/projectThumbnails/image01.jpg",
    extra: (<div>Extra 01</div>),

  },
  {
    id: "6853939",
    name: "Project 02",
    title: "Title 02 ",
    previewImg: "/images/projectThumbnails/image02.jpg",
    extra: (<div>Extra 02</div>),
  }
];

export default projects;
```

**index.tsx**

```
import projects from "../data/projects.tsx";

const IndexPage = ({projects}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {projects.map((i) => (
          <div key={i.id}>{i.title}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        {names.names.map((i) => (
          <div key={i.name}>{i.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: { projects: projects },
  };
};
```

Comment: Not sure if you need `getStaticProps` in this case, you could try doing it without it. Another thing you could try is using a dynamic import inside `getStaticProps`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of props returned from the `getStaticProps` needs to be serializable i.e. it can be converted to a string (language agnostic representation which can be shared among different languages) with `JSON.stringify()` and back to its original value with `JSON.parse()` again. JavaScript `function`, `Symbol`, `JSX`, etc. are not serializable property.

Here is what's supported. https://www.json.org/json-en.html

In your projects array, the value of the `extra` key is a JSX element that is not a serializable property:

```js
const projects: [
  {
    id: "6853939",
    name: "Project 01",
    title: "Title 01 ",
    previewImg: "/images/projectThumbnails/image01.jpg",
    extra: (<div>Extra 01</div>), // <= this is not serializable property

  },
  {
    id: "6853939",
    name: "Project 02",
    title: "Title 02 ",
    previewImg: "/images/projectThumbnails/image02.jpg",
    extra: (<div>Extra 02</div>), // <= this is not serializable property
  }
];

export default projects;
```

Thus you are getting this error.

```
Error: Error serializing `.projects[0].extra.$$typeof` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/index".
Reason: `symbol` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

You can change the value of extra to a string instead and the error should be fixed. For eg.: `extra: "Extra 02"` and use the string to print value inside of div in the component.

Comment: Will the site still be a cached static page if I don't use getStaticProps in this case? As it's imported from a `.ts` file and not a `.json` file.

Comment: Even if you don't use `getStaticProps` Next.js will statically generate the page at build time. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-recommended.